# Unable to return token from AsyncStorage in React Native

Tags: authentication, react-native, token, es6-promise, asyncstorage

I am using React Native's AsyncStorage to store an authorization token, which will be returned when needed to use for new http requests. While I can successfully store it and console log it, I am having some trouble returning the value. I want to call it in another window, in the fashion of

```
 var x= LocalDb.getAcessToken();
 console.log(x);
```

However it won,t work.

```
 LocalDb.getAccessToken();
```

This on the other hand, works when  getAcessToken() has console.log in it

```
exports.storeToken=function(token){
  AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', token);
  }
```

^^^^This function successfully saves the token

```
exports.getAccessToken=function(){
   AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token')
   .then((value) => {
       if(value) {
        console.log(value);
    **//I want to return the value here, to use in another function**
      }
    })
  .done();
}
```

I can not return the value when I use the return(value) . How can I return a value from the promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the `getAccessToken` function with the promise call. I would also return the promise with the value... like this.

```
exports.getAccessToken=function(){
 return AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token')
 .then((value) => {
     if(value) {
      console.log(value);
      return value;
    }
   })
}
```

Comment: I also don't think you need to call the `.done()` call.